# How to enable enums directive in Struts2 for FreeMarker results?

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

Say I have an Enum class "sample.enums.Enum", and I have a Struts2 applications with default configuration for the most part.

If I [configure my BeanWrappers](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#jdk_15_enums) correctly, this should work.

```
${enums["java.math.RoundingMode"].UP}
```

It does not work.  How do I configure my Struts2 FreeMarker configuration to allow for the enums directive.

i.e.

```
root.put("enums", BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance().getEnumModels());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok its not difficult, Just extend FreemarkerManager and override

```
@Override
public SimpleHash buildTemplateModel(ValueStack stack, Object action, ServletContext ervletContext, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ObjectWrapper wrapper)
```

In that method, set the enums hash model on the model.  Then set a struts property,

```
<constant name="struts.freemarker.manager.classname" value="your.freemarker.ConfigClass">
```